# I want to split the data in the list when i see the ; in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

[image]

I need to split this data in the box to and add it to new line when it see the ";"

```
var retryParamInfo = new ExParamsContent 
{ 
    Idenitifier = tempIdentifier.SerialNumber, 
    Name = String.Format( "Retry Information Console {0}",i), 
    Value = MyTestRunGlobals.FixtureComponents[i].Uuts[0].RetryList, 
    //Value = thisUut.RetryList.Replace("\n", "\n" + Environment.NewLine), 
}; 
uutTempInfo.ExParams.Add(retryParamInfo);
```

Comment: var retryParamInfo = new ExParamsContent
                            {
                                Idenitifier = tempIdentifier.SerialNumber,
                                Name = String.Format( "Retry Information Console {0}",i),
                                Value = MyTestRunGlobals.FixtureComponents[i].Uuts[0].RetryList,
                          

                                //Value = thisUut.RetryList.Replace("\n", "\n" + Environment.NewLine),
                            }; 
                            uutTempInfo.ExParams.Add(retryParamInfo);

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring it out. Did you have a programming question? This site is for questions, not a place to dump your to-do/requirements list.

Comment: Why you don't use    yourString.Split(';') ?

Comment: invalid expression error

Comment: Please don't paste code into a comment like that. It's completely unreadable. Edit your question and format it properly.

Answer (score 1):

To split a string when some character occours, you can use:

```
myString.split(';');
```

and make the result of this be inside a array.